# How can I store images so that the URL for the image takes me only to the image and not the webpage?

Tags: active-directory, photo, imageurl

I am connecting Active Directory to a platform my company uses. In order to ensure that user's have a profile picture, I will add the URL of the photo to an attribute and connect it that way. However, the URL for the image must take me directly to the image. So far, I have been able to store images on different options but for each one, when I select the URL, it takes me to the webpage that disples other items than just the image (e.g. - https://ibb.co/J2cFfsx ). How can I store photos so that the URL takes me directly to JUST the image ONLY?

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but AD does have an attribute specifically designed for holding a picture of the person, which programs like Outlook or Skype for Business automatically read and display. It's called [thumbnailPhoto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-thumbnailphoto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on the image and click view image. once you have done this you should get something that looks like below. In the URL there should be a new link, if you use that one it should always take you to the image aslong as it exits.

Equally you can right click on the image and select "copy image location" and that will give you the new link. I personally perfer the other method as it gives a proper preview of the image at its full size.

[new image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg72x.png)

Comment: Wow, that was so easy. And it works, thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

To link your image to the document go and search for image on google. right click on image -> Create QR code for this image after showing the QR code. Beneath QR code there is a link copy that and paste it in your document where you want. Now just to be sure click on the link and it will show the image only. Try it!!